# jsonp method in HttpClient is not returning error status 0 instead of the correct one

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

The problem I'm facing is, when using the jsonp method in HttpClient, it is not returning the proper error, instead it always gives this one:

[HttpErrorResponse with status 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZYdU.png)

It seems like for the get method, the returned error is as intended, but not for the jsonp method.

In my code in particular, I'm forced to use the jsonp method, because otherwise I'd get a CORS error. It works fine when the HTTP request goes through, but when I get the 429 status code, it returns the status 0 error.

I made a simple repo on stackblitz, to show what happens when the request returns an error 429 with both the get, and jsonp methods. The former returns the proper error, the latter does not. I also made it easy to test for other status code, so you can play around with it. [Here you can find a list of the suported status.](https://httpstat.us/)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mqdyzr?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Expected result:

[HttpErrorResponse with status 429](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84nn3.png)

Actual result:

[HttpErrorResponse with status 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZYdU.png)

Comment: i think getting status codes is an issue with jsonp, not with angular